# QGIS 3.10 export layer group into arbitrary GIS formats e.g. KML, SHP and etc

Tags: qgis

I would like to export the layer group created in QGIS into the GIS file extensions as: .kml, .shp, etc.

So far, the "Export" option available for this layer group gives a chance to export as a "Layer Definition File" in .qlr extension only.

[image]

I would like to have more options for saving this groupped layer.

Comment: What is wrong with `save object as`, the topmost option in the export-group?

Comment: I can save it only as of the Layer Definition file with .qlr extension. I want to have it as the .kml for example.

Comment: Are you just trying to export each layer in the group to its own GIS file (as in your output would be graze.kml, mid.kml, limb.kml) ? Have you tried the batch vector layer saver plugin? Should solve your problem

Comment: I am trying to export them as the one .kml layer.

Comment: @MapInfoNewbie, as far as I can see the plugin 'Batch Vector Layer Saver' can only save to CSV, SHP, GeoJSON, GPGK, MapInfo amd PGDump. OP wanted to export to KML. 

I usually export to KML one by one, edit and group in Google Earth Pro, and save as KMZ from there. :-/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "layer group" is not a single layer. It's multiple separate layers. They are grouped together in the Layer panel for your convenience. But you can't export a Layer Group as a single layer.

You can combine any layers that are the same type of vector data (eg, all polygons) using the tool, `Merge Vector Layers`. The line layer cannot be combined into a single shapefile with the polygon layers. That's a limitation of the shapefile format.

The KML format supports multiple data types, however I don't think QGIS can create a KML file with different data types. To combine the three layers into a KML file, you will probably have to use different software (such as Google Earth).

Database-type formats can combine multiple separate layers in a single file. This includes formats such as Geopackage and Spatialite.

- To combine the layers in a Geopackage file, use the tool `Package Layers`.
- To combine them into any other database format, export one of the layers in that format. Select the other two layers, then drag and drop them into that database.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with a similar issue stitching Points and Lines together in one KML-file.
The solution is pretty much straight forward like dealing with GeoPackages using pyQgis.
You need to create a KML-file upfront and add other geometry types to it by running the below script.
Works for me on QGIS 3.14.15.

```
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    file_path = r'c:/temp/KML.kml'

    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    options.driverName = "KML"
    options.layerName = "hurtz_3"
    options.forceMulti = True
    options.actionOnExistingFile = 
    QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer 
    options.EditionCapability = QgsVectorFileWriter.CanAddNewLayer
 
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer,
    file_path,
    QgsCoordinateTransformContext(),
    options)
```

Behaviour is like an e.g Geo package while importing again.
Where the added layer is the currently activated Layer and the KML is the formerly saved target data-set.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Install the [bulkvectorexport plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/BulkVectorExport/).